# Solr bf parameters

Tags: solr

I was reading through the apache solr module and noticed this:

bf = recip(rord(created),4,90785,90785)^200.0

Could someone explain what this does? It looks like it adds boast to the created field, but i am not sure what all the functions are (recip, rord)

Answer (score 4):

The solr function query methods are documented on the Solr Wiki:

- [recip](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#recip)
- [rord](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#rord)

So, the boost query you provided gives a boost to newer documents, using this function that looks like:

> (90785/(4*rord(created) + 90785))^200

The newest document:

> (90785/(4*1 + 90785))^200  => 0.9912

And the oldest document (assuming 1000 documents):

> (90785/(4*1000 + 90785))^200 => 0.0001798

Comment: I am also not able to get this. bf=x^y how it will impact my score? sometimes it goes beyond 1. I am unable to get , how bf works?